# aloha-editor package shows errors when enabled

Tags: javascript, requirejs, meteor, aloha-editor

When aloha-editor package is added to meteor project, it starts showing console errors on load:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { return Spinner }
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
```

It seems there is a conflict with RequireJS which is used by aloha-editor.
Given link for resolution doesn't help, it contains something about using RequireJS Optimizer, however I have no idea what does it mean exactly.

Does anyone know how exactly this error can be fixed?

Comment: thanks for the information -- I'll update Aloha Editor to the latest version and try to fix the error if it still exists (in the next days)

Comment: @rene.kapusta please post any updates here when the error will be fixed, thanks in advance.

Comment: @aram90 Does this error still occur?